# SQL Server 2008 - Update Query Timeout

Tags: .net, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL2008 and .NET 4.

The following **UPDATE** query causes timeout errors.

Table **Pages** has 600,000 records.

Error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The
>   timeout period elapsed prior to
>   completion of the operation or the
>   server is not responding.

Query:

```
UPDATE  Pages
SET Checked = 1  , LastChecked = GETDATE()
OUTPUT Inserted.ID, Inserted.Title INTO @Updated
WHERE ID in 
 (SELECT TOP (@Count) ID 
  FROM Pages 
  WHERE Checked = 0 and FileID = @FileID 
  ORDER BY ID)

SELECT * FROM @Updated  
END
```

On a different thread I Insert records to `Pages` table, this runs continually (a page is added every 1 sec or less).

```
INSERT INTO Pages (Title ,.......)
VALUES (@Title , .......)
```

Why do I get the timeout error and how can I solve it?

Doesn't SQL wait indefinitely on blocking situation ?

Answer (score 2):

It's your command/client that's timing out, rather than SQL Server itself.

Perhaps adjust your `SqlCommand.CommandTimeout` to a higher value?

```
 myCmd.CommandTimeout = 360; //seconds
```

**Updates:**

Are you sure your 1 second `UPDATE` statement is the one being blocked/timing out? Perhaps there's something else executing just previous?

Have you looked at SSMS to determine what is being blocked/blocking? Right click your server, select 'Activity Monitor'.
[image]

What does SQL Profiler show you as being executed?

Comment: Its just too easy to extend the timeout every time the query performances to slow . i think i should fully investigate if there is something to improve.

Comment: "Have you looked at SSMS to determine what is being blocked/blocking?" , can you please explain how to do this ?

Comment: thx for the update. the exception is thrown randomly every 10-100 mintues. is there some way to log the blocking events ?

Comment: @sharru: what does SQL Profiler show as being sent to the server? Are you using LINQ To SQL, or ADO.NET commands? Is the exception thrown randomly for just this query, or other queries to the DB server?

Answer (score 1):

Updating 600,000 rows is a lot of work for SQL.

WHERE IN is a fairly inefficient way to do this clause, I would use:

```
UPDATE TOP(@Count) Pages
   SET Checked = 1, LastChecked = GETDATE()
OUTPUT Inserted.ID, Inserted.Title INTO @Updated
WHERE Checked = 0 and FileID = @FileID
```

Make sure that @Count is fairly small, between 2000 and 10,000

Answer (score 0):

As (+1) p.campbell said, the timeout is coming from .NET, not from SQL.

What indexing do you have in place? Without suitable coverage of columns "Checked" and/or "ID", your subquery (SELECT TOP...) will have to read every page in the table, to first get all where Checked = 0 and then sort those by ID.  If it's large and being regularly updated that could make it Delay Central.

If they don't have to be ordered by Id, taking out that ORDER BY might cause the query to only read rows until it gets @Count of them.

If you have SQL 2008, a filtered query (...WHERE Checked = 0) might speed things up.

Comment: Executing the query from SQL Server management studio takes 1 second and uses non-clusteed index (cost 100%).

Comment: If it works properly through SSMS but not through your .net code, then I'd focus on the .net code. It may be a locking/blocking problem (as per p.campbell), but odds are it'll be somthing to do with your connectivity layer, something I don't have that much experience with.